# How to change connexion string in a deployed Azure App

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have developed a website application under visual studio using the MVC Pattern and Entity Framework 6.
This web app was linked to a local database.

I've published the application on my azure acc. I also exported the database on Azure following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-migrate-your-sql-server-database).
However, I can't find a way to link the online app to the migrated database.

No data is displayed on the app and when I try to check for the connexion string I get [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcSqO.png) , the connexion string hasn't been updated and therefore the app is still trying to target my local database.

I would like to know if anyone might know how to solve this.

EDIT : The problem may be somewhere else, I apparently have [two connexions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkDgj.png) , one for my migrated DB and one for my local db. Perhaps I need to remove the connexion string targetting my local DB but I don't know how to do that
Also, since the Migrated database is a copy from the local one I was using before, do I need to change anything in my Model,views or controller ?

EDIT2 : Thanks to the comment below I was able to override the false Connexion String. However my datas are still not displayed on my application and I haven't found yet what could have happend. 
I suspect that my model is still the same model as the one used by the local database as it has the same name. Does anybody know how to change the model to the current model of the online database ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because you created your app with entity framework there should be a connection string defined in the web.config file pointing to the local database.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="..."  
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

If you have published your Website as WebApp (App Service) then you can change the connection string for the database under the Application Settings pane on the WebApp Page.
You can override your connection string by creating a connection string settings entry with the name of the connection string in the web.config file.
(For the snippet above - MyContext)

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment, I now only have one connexion string which's valid. However the datas from the database are still not displayed . I tried to make a local copy of the pre deployed app and I have access to the online database and can edit it. Do you know what else could have possibly gone wrong ? Thanks